# Fitting Data to distributions

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, distributions, bayesian, normal-distribution

Suppose we have 1-Dimensional data $x=[-1, 0, 1]$. (We suppose that these points have been generated by a Gaussian Distribution with $μ=0$ and $σ=1$)

1. Suppose that I'd like to find the parameters ($μ$ and $σ$) of the distribution as if I didn't know them. We can do the max likelihood estimation of the parameters $μ$ and $σ$ like this:

   \begin{align}
   μ &= \frac{\sum_{i=1}^I x_{i}}{Ι}  \\[5pt]
   σ^2 &= \sum\limits_{i=1}^I \frac{(x_{i}-μ)^2}{Ι}
   \end{align}

   I get $μ=0$ (which is correct), but then $σ^2$ becomes $0.66$. When I use MATLAB's function to fit it, it gets the correct result.
2. Let's say that instead of normal it was a uniform distribution. The question is, which $k$, that belongs to $[-k, k]$ is the one that fits the data the highest? The pdf of a uniform is $\frac{1}{b-a}$ and I believe that this $k=1$ but I am not quite sure how to prove it.

Comment: I can't follow your question, it seems very confusingly worded to the extent that I can't clearly tell what you're describing For example, what do you mean by [-1,0,1] and how does that relate to the Gaussian?

Comment: @Glen_b I am sorry for the confusion. X is the data vector, which is 1-dimensional. We got one point x1=-1 , another x2=0 and another x3=1 . These data points supposed to been drawn from a 1-D gaussian distribution. If you need further clarification inform me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This solution for $\sigma$ is the correct most-likely normal distribution. You asserted that the data $\{-1, 0, 1\}$ came from a normal distribution with mean zero and standard deviation 1. Well, I say that I drew some data from a normal distribution with mean $5$ and standard deviation $10$, and guess what I got: 1, -1, and 0. What a coincidence!

   There's nothing about your purported sample that makes it associated with what you said; it *could* be that, but really the max-likelihood normal distribution is the one with mean 0 and variance $2/3$.
2. You are correct that it's $k=1$.

   The PDF of a uniform distribution on $[a, b]$ is actually $$f(x) = \begin{cases}\frac1{b-a} & a\le x \le b \\ 0 &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}.$$ So the likelihood of your dataset for a uniform distribution on $[-k,k]$ is 0 when $k < 1$ and $\frac1{(2k)^3}$ otherwise. The likelihood is maximal, then, when $k=1$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I still don't get why Matlab finds that best fit for sigma as 1. Anyway, that $\frac1{(2k)^3}$, how did it come up?

Comment: Matlab isn't doing maximum likelihood but instead using [Bessel's correction](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_correction) of dividing by $I-1$ instead of $I$; it happens to work out to 1 in this case.

Comment: For the uniform distribution, the density on $[a, b]$ is $\frac1{b-a}$, so the density on $[-k, k]$ is $\frac1{k - (-k)} = \frac1{2k}$. To get the likelihood for the dataset, you multiply the likelihood of each point, which is how it gets cubed for your dataset of size three.